# Android Add UI Elements to a CustomView class

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, view, android-custom-view

I have created a CustomView class, a class that extends View.

In this view I would like to be able to add UI elements like a Linear Layout with Buttons, TextViews etc.

How should I do this in the most efficient way?

Comment: you can always extend it with a FrameLayout :)

Comment: Okay, thanks! But if I want to add another Custom View on top of that View. How does it work then?